# Precipitation, etc

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> Precipitation, falling from heavy clouds,
>
> Crashing down onto delicate flowers.
>
> Thin sensory organs placed on
>
> Young feline mammals.
>
> Glimmering metallic sheen of No. 29,
>
> Forming the maker of tea.
>
> Farm animal covering turned
>
> Warm sack of digits.
>
> The processed pulp of a tree,
>
> Folded, covering a prism
>
> And bound in organic chains.
>
> ---
>
> The shade of a milk product
>
> Decorating a small horse.
>
> Non-soft German desert
>
> filled with some Malus.
>
> Tingling arrival notifications,
>
> both stationary and mobile.
>
> Thin breaded meat served with
>
> Thin sliced smooth wheat.
>
> V-forming live things,
>
> sailing on feathers,
>
> moving past the Reflector.

---

What am I describing?

*Two sections are included; a final section will be added if no one gets the answer soon. I doubt this one will go very long without being solved.*

**BONUS:** Write the third section yourself following my pattern. No real incentive; just if you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like

> your favorite things!

because

> it's describing the lyrics of the song "My Favorite Things" from *The Sound of Music*

Precipitation, falling from heavy clouds, Crashing down onto delicate flowers.
Thin sensory organs placed on
Young feline mammals.

> Raindrops on roses and whiskers on kittens

Glimmering metallic sheen of No. 29, Forming the maker of tea.
Farm animal covering turned Warm sack of digits.

> Bright copper kettles and warm woolen mittens

The processed pulp of a tree, Folded, covering a prism And bound in organic chains.

> Brown paper packages tied up with strings

---

The shade of a milk product Decorating a small horse.
Non-soft German desert filled with some Malus.

> Cream-colored ponies and crisp apple strudels

Tingling arrival notifications, both stationary and mobile.
Thin breaded meat served with Thin sliced smooth wheat.

> Doorbells and sleigh bells and schnitzel with noodles

V-forming live things, sailing on feathers, moving past the Reflector.

> Wild geese that fly with the moon on their wings

---

> **These are a few of my favorite things**

Comment: Heh, yeah, I thought this one would go quickly, but I didn't think it would fall _this_ fast. Said details, of course, are wanted for the final answer/checkmark.

Comment: Typing them right now - just didn't want to get sniped ;)

Comment: No problem! Take your time.

Comment: @Brandon_J As another data-point on how fast: I saw the puzzle's notification in TSL, read the line about young feline mammals, and immediately knew what the solution was going to be. So maybe 5 seconds from first sight of the puzzle to knowing the answer :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yay and drat. Thanks for letting me know.